# Audio not being consistently transmitted over HDMI from computer to TV since upgrade to Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, audio, hdmi, nvidia-graphics-card

I have an LG TV and a PC with a Geforce GT 220 graphics card connected via HDMI.
While the PC was running Windows 8.1 it would transmit audio over the HDMI no problem.
Since upgrading to Windows 10 it does not transmit the audio by default, although I can get it to work if I change the display size via the NVidia control panel, or if I toggle the ratio setting on the TV (16:9 by default, toggle to 4:3, then back to 16:9).
It will also start working again if I toggle the refresh rate of the monitor in the computer settings.

I can see the TV listed for the HDMI output in the Playback devices tab of Sounds, and it is enabled and set to the default.
I have manually upgraded the NVidia drivers to the latest version available from their website.
The display size is defaulting to 1920x1080 (Native) at 60Hz which I believe is 1080p.

I previously had what appeared to be the same issue with an Xbox 360 where I had to toggle the ratio to get the sound to work when I would start a DVD or NetFlix on the Xbox, but an Xbox One works correctly out of the box.

Can anyone suggest anything else I could try, I'm at a loss as to what else I can do?
I know that the workaround of toggling the ratio isn't hard to do, but I'd just like to fix the problem once and for all or at least understand the origin of the issue.